# EventStore - issues integrating with protobuf-net

Tags: cqrs

I was looking at using EventStore with SQL Server for the data storage. Most of the performance hit is with SQL Server actually storing the data, and there is a lot of memory allocated in the web server as well.
It turns out it all boils down to the Serialization of the headers (from CommonDomain's EventStoreRepository class) and of the EventMessage (from EventStore).

So I tried to switch from the Binary Serializer to the Protobuf-net one. But the types that need serialization do not have the required attributes to be properly serialized.

Is it possible to use protobuf-net with EventStore + CommonDomain? Has anyone done it?

Comment: Why not just add `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract` attributes to the events you wish to serialize?

Comment: That does work well for binary serialization, but the resulting stream is a bit large. If I add [ProtoContract] to the classes and use a proto serializer I can get the size of the message to be much lower.

Comment: For now I implemented an ISerialize that sniffs the types being serialized by CommonDomain/EventStore and serializes with protobuf over multiple calls (for each event, then the event body type name, then the event body itself and so on). Size of the store dropped 90% and speed went up (full command execution takes 20% less time). Still toying around with this. Currently my implementation ignores header information streaming except for the EventType header.

Comment: Antonio, any progress? Can u share the protobuf implementation?